# How to change python window title?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change the title text to other names but i don't know the command.

Like from C:\windows\py.exe to a better looking title like Python but I cannot find how to do it.

I need the Python 3.10 version of Windows command 'title ...'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Open cmd, run `title`, run `py.exe`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os` module system command `os.system("title your title")`.

Comment: You could possibly add that to your site setup